# Can obfuscated code be useful sometimes?

Tags: c#, obfuscation

While creating a custom 3D `Point` class with single-precision coordinate values in C#, I had to write a method to calculate the distance between two points. Then I thought about the `A -> B` graph notation meaning "from A to B", and I thought about overloading the `>` operator, as it has no sense thinking about a point A being "greater" than a point B (besides, the `->` operator cannot be overloaded).

So I created the following methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the Manhattan distance between the two points.
/// </summary>
public static float operator>(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) +
           Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y) +
           Math.Abs(p1.Z - p2.Z);
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculates the euclidean distance between the two points.
/// </summary>
public static double operator>=(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X, 2) +
                     Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2) +
                     Math.Pow(p1.Z - p2.Z, 2));
}
```

This results in code like this:

```
var manhattan = A > B;
var euclidean = A >= B;
```

The code seems to be obfuscated but once you get the grasp of it, it is quite simple to read, and shorter than using `A.DistanceTo(B)`.

The question is, should I completely avoid this kind of code? If so, what's the reason why? I am quite concerned with Clean Code, and I'm not sure this could be considered *clean* or not. If you think such code is sometimes allowed, could you provide examples?

Comment: In this particular case, yes, because the `>=` operator is almost universally known as "greater than or equal to", and you're subverting that heavily here.  Most people would look at that operator and think "why doesn't it tell me if `A` is greater than `B`?"

Comment: In 6 months you'll be maintaining your code and start wondering why you are checking if A is greater than B. Is it so bad to use a `DistanceTo` method instead? That, to me, more clearly explains what you are doing.

Comment: Maybe you can take another operator which don't make sense with classes, like >> (bit displacement)

Comment: Also, greater and greater equal do make sense for a point, think of it as a vector, you can take it's length and then compare them...

Comment: @DangerZone, there is never only one person working on a project.  At minimum, there is you-right-now, and you-in-the-future-trying-to-maintain-your-own-code.  This kind of too-cute-by-half operator redefinition is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Gusman You're right, I could choose another operator to overload. About your other comment, a Point and a Vector are just different things (in fact, in C# both concepts have separate classes).

Comment: Yes, I know, but, sometimes is very useful to check the distance to 0,0 from a point, in this case is just the length. Also think about what others  said, it's not only you the one who is working on the project, tomorrow what you thought that doesn't make sense may do, so it can be confusing. A binary operator is just completely nonsense, you can't move the bits of a class, so if you don't remember what it does it forces to read the code.

Comment: It seems like this question should be migrated to codereview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should avoid this kind of code (unless perhaps it is part of a more in-depth DSL).

Overriding common operators and methods with unexpected behaviour makes it very hard to pick up, understand and debug the code.

Imagine you're reading a book and although the words look like english the author has changed the meanings of several key words by making some notes in an appendix at the back, so you're constantly flipping back and forth to check each sentence means what you think it does.

Code should be written to be read by humans.  The easier you make that task and the fewer surprises you incorporate the better it will be.

Comment: I understand completely your answer, but then how do you explain functional programming languages such as F#? Code in those languages are all but readable, yet they are increasing their popularity.

Comment: Also, in game (3d programs, you get me ;) ) math is very common to replace operators, per example, a very usual change is to change the "*" operator to the dot product for vectors.

Comment: I'd argue that the readability of functional languages is just a question of familiarity.  Functional languages can be highly readable (and concise!).  The important part is if I learn F# I should write it in the canonical style so it's easy for someone else who knows F# to read it.

Comment: @Gusman A dot product for vectors *is* multiplication in that context, so that's actually using the multiplication operator to perform multiplication.

Comment: @Servy Yes and no, a multiplication should return the same type of object and the dot product returns an scalar from a struct/class, so it's not exactly the same, a multiplication would be { x = a.x * b.x, y = a.y * b.y }

Comment: @Gusman But that's *not* how multiplication is defined for vectors.  It's not a requirement of the operation that it return something of the same type.

Comment: OK, I knew that what I was doing was not _orthodox_, but I didn't know it was THAT bad. That's what happens when you experiment: you fail sometimes. So I accept your answer (besides, I've got enough negative votes for my first question ;) )